# I am getting this error "ORA-01008: not all variables bound ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721" while running a command in livesql

Tags: sql, oracle

Question.
Write a PL/SQL program to check whether a date falls on weekend i.e.
‘SATURDAY’ or ‘SUNDAY’.

I tried running the code on livesql.oracle.com

My Code:
[image]

I am very new to sql and don't really know why i am getting this error.
It is saying that all variables are not bound.
Please help.

The output which I was expecting is:
[image]

I tried changing single quotes to double but that didn't work.

Comment: Well you are not getting that error from `MySQL` so please dont tag it. I would suggest you tag Oracle instead

Comment: Code, errors and data should be posted as (formatted) text, not as image

Comment: My bad, i didn't knew that we should not post screenshots of code. This was my first question and i was very desperate at that to find an answer, that's why I didn't bothered with checking that how I should post a question. I will be careful from next time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why LiveSQL complains but - nonetheless - your code wouldn't work because of a wrong format model. `DAY` would return day name in uppercase, right-padded with spaces up to the longest day name (in your language). You're comparing such a name with initcap day name with no right-padded spaces so - all days wouldn't be a weekend, regardless of what you enter.

This is a SQL*Plus example so I'm using a substitution variable.

First, setting date format and language (because my database's default format is different than this, and my database speaks Croatian, not English):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_language = 'english';

Session altered.
```

Now, code:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2   d   date;
  3   day varchar2(20);
  4  begin
  5    -- d := :input_a_date;                --> your
  6    d := '&input_a_date';                 --> mine
  7
  8    day := to_char(d, 'fmDay');           --> pay attention to format model!
  9
 10    if day in ('Saturday', 'Sunday') then
 11       dbms_output.put_Line('Day is ' || day || ' and is a weekend');
 12    else
 13       dbms_output.put_line('Day is ' || day || ' and is not a weekend');
 14    end if;
 15  end;
 16  /
Enter value for input_a_date: 30.10.2022
Day is Sunday and is a weekend

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> /
Enter value for input_a_date: 02.11.2022
Day is Wednesday and is not a weekend

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Live SQL does not have a mechanism to prompt for bind variables. It also has no way to assign values to bind variables from the SQL Worksheet. Bind variables may only be used in Live SQL within dynamic SQL. See below for examples using **EXECUTE IMMEDIATE** or **DBMS_SQL**.

[Live SQL: Dynamic SQL: Don't concatenate, bind!](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_CLR0BBF716JGT4KNFWBO9EYK1.html)

[Live SQL: Method 4 Dynamic SQL Example: Display contents of table](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_CXZTYYXU7AQNK1HPVZ98AR59J.html)